# How to make autolayout work with custom UIView on XIB?

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

I have a `UIView` on a XIB, containing an `UIImageView` and a `UILabel` with a small space in between.  Horizontal layout is a simple chained `|--image--label--|` in which `--` is some fixed space.  The height is fixed to 40, this view is horizontally centred in its view controller, and it has an `>=` 100 width constraint.

If I change the label text, the width of my composed view updates as expected width the changed width of its label, and it stays nicely centred on the view controller.

Because I need this `UIView`, containing an image and label, in other places, I've created a custom class consisting of a XIB and Swift file. Let's call it `ItemView`.

Issue I have is that the empty `UIView` on my view controller XIB, which I've changed class to `ItemView`, no longer accepts the `>=` 40 width constraint.  This is of course because the view controller XIB no longer sees the variable width `UILabel`, but instead just a plain `UIView` of class `ItemView`.  I get an 'Inequality Constraint Ambiguity' IB error.

The result is that the width of my custom view remains 40.  It works a little bit if I specify a larger >= label width; the text is then only cut off when this width is reached. But in that second case my custom view is no longer horizontally centred, but shifted a bit to the left instead.

How do I resolve this?  Or, how can I tell IB to treat my custom `ItemView` in a similar way as a `UILabel`?

In my `ItemView` I've done all I could find:

```
override class var requiresConstraintBasedLayout: Bool
{
    return true
}
```

Call `setNeedsLayout()` after setting the label text.

Call `myLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`.

Call `self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`.

And call `self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` in both `init()`s.

Comment: Why not just turn off the warning for this view? You can simply tell IB not to check the autolayout validity for this view.

Comment: Are you trying to use the custom XIB as `@IBDesignable`, and that's when you're getting the error / warning?

Comment: @DonMag It's an IB layout error.  I haven't specified `@IBDesignable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I structured my custom `UIView`: My XIB's Files Owner is `ItemView`. `ItemView` has an `@IBOutlet var: UIView!` that's connected to the view in the XIB. Then I have:

```
init()
{
    super.init(frame: .zero)

    self.initView()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.initView()
}

private func initView()
{
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ItemView", owner: self, options: nil)
    self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.width, height: self.height)
    self.addSubview(self.view!)
}
```

(I seems this extra `UIView` is needed when creating a custom `UIView` with a XIB. Would love to hear if it's not needed after all.)

To make it work I needed to call `self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()` after updating the label.  And override `intrinsicContentSize`:

```
override open var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize
{
    return self.view.systemLayoutSizeFitting(self.bounds.size)
}
```

Note that I'm calling this on `self.view`, not on `self`.

Thanks @matt for pointing me in the right direction. Was the first time I've encountered something like this.

The following things I tried we all not necessary:

```
override class var requiresConstraintBasedLayout: Bool
{
    return true
}
```

Call `setNeedsLayout()` after setting the label text.

Call `myLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`.

Call `self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`.

And call `self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` in both `init()`s.

Answer (score 1):

Configure this pop-up in the view's Size inspector:

[image]

Now IB won't worry about your size specifications. You know better than IB does, and this is how to tell IB that fact.

---

Another way: configure *this* pop-up in the view's Size inspector:

[image]

This tells IB that the view will have an intrinsic content size that it doesn't know about.

---

Either of those will work. As you can see in this screenshot, I've given my custom view a width constraint of greater-than-or-equal-to-40, but IB is not complaining of any error:

[image]

Comment: That indeed removes the error, but my custom `UIView` does not update its width at all.

Comment: No, of course not. How can it? It has no known width until runtime. But you can still apply autolayout relationships to it, and all will be well at runtime if you configure things correctly. However, that is a different matter! You asked how to silence the warning when using a placeholder view in IB, and I answered that.

Comment: I've updated the question with more details. Apologies for the developing 'story'. My question however has been 'how to make autolayout work' from the start.

Comment: Well obviously you need your custom view to implement `instrinsicContentSize` in such a way that it sizes itself based on the label. No?

Comment: `instrinsicContentSize` seems to be the key. But why doesn't autolayout work here, and I need to calculate manually? Can I at least ask my custom view to calculate it's width based on its constrainst? I'm clearly missing something.

Comment: You seem to think a view magically calculates its size based on the constraints of its subviews? It doesn't. You can call `systemLayout` to get the calculated size based on the internal constraints, but it isn't going to happen magically by itself.